# Array of macros in C

Tags: c

**Can I do array of macros**

I am trying to define array of macros, Please check the below code and let me know can I do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

struct da
{
    unsigned char d1:1;
    unsigned char d2:1;
};

struct da stDataVar;

#define DATA_1 stDataVar.d1
#define DATA_2 stDataVar.d2 = 1

unisgned char arrChar[2] = {DATA_1, DATA_2};

main()
{
 
printf("data = %d\n",arrChar[0]);

}
```

Comment: Using bitfields implies you are using C99, which requires you to specify return types for functions (there is no more default-`int`).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you give an example, please?

Comment: There's no such thing as an array of macros. The macro is simply replaced with its expansion. Perform the replacement yourself and see if the result looks correct to you.

Comment: `unisgned` is misspelled. Is that a copying error or in your real code?

Comment: @dreamlax bitfields are in C89 (and in K&R)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Of course they are! What was I thinking ...

Comment: Unclear what your actual goal is, since the question's presumption that an 'array of macros' is a thing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to have "an array of macros". In your case, the macros probably just obfuscate the code. In particular, you shouldn't hide side effects inside macros that you are using for initialization.

Is there any reason why you can't do like this?

```
// elsewhere in the code:
stDataVar.d2 = 1;

...

unsigned char arrChar[2] = 
{ 
  stDataVar.d1,
  stDataVar.d2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

arrChar[0] is the 1st element of arrChar[2] i.e. DATA_1 which is a macro that gets textually replaced by the preprocessor as stDataVar.d1 which is structure stDataVar(of type struct da)'s d1 bit field which is zero or garbage (depends on compiler if that initializes a character by default)